# PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'lgbtc204_dev.image_dimensions' doesn't exist:

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, module

Just migrated my local site to the server under /dev.

http://lgbtcampaign.org/dev/

Everything seems to be working fine except the "Share" page. Also it wont let me access the "content" of the site through the UI. It works fine on local.

http://lgbtcampaign.org/dev/content/share-portal

This is the error I'm getting on both pages.

PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'lgbtc204_dev.image_dimensions' doesn't exist: SELECT * FROM {image_dimensions} id WHERE id.fid IN (:fids_0, :fids_1); Array ( [:fids_0] => 20 [:fids_1] => 22 ) in file_entity_file_load() (line 225 of /home/lgbtc204/public_html/dev/sites/all/modules/media/file_entity/file_entity.module).

Any ideas what I need to do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Either the base table or view does not exist, as it says, or the userid you're using to connect to the db server doesn't have permissions to it.

Comment: How do I correct those issues?

Comment: Do you have the same database in both environments?